# Limit number of field return from mongodb in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am have a collection that stores documents that contains user informations like Email, Phone Number, etc.

I want to be able to return only 5 fields that exist in the document, for example.

> Email: [a@a.com, b@b.com]
>
> Mobile: [012345, 6789]
>
> Country: USA
>
> Service: [Wholesale, Retail]
>
> Zip: 30001
>
> City: New York

It will return:

> a@a.com, 012345, USA, Wholesale, 30001

or if the document is

> Service: [Wholesale, Retail]
>
> Zip: 30001
>
> City: New York

It will return:

> Wholesale, 30001, New York

Basically limits the number of fields to return to 5 fields, and if that field is an array, then only return first item in that array.

My english is not that good but I have tried my best to explain my problem, if any part is unclear I'd be happy to try to explain further.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit: It would be fine even if I could impose this kind of limit on handlebars/spacebars instead of cursor. Whatever works~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to transfer your collection in another ( result ) array, and to retrieve this array in your handlebar template :

```
Users  = new Meteor.Collection("users"); 
LIMIT =4;

Template.userShow.users = function () {
    var users = Users.find().fetch();
    for (var i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
        result[i] =  users[i];  
    }
    return result ;
};
```

Comment: This actually works, but it still doesn't account for fields that is an array. But that's probably not to difficult by using if statement inside for loop. Thanks. I think I got it!!

Comment: I don't understand - will this not just limit the number of users? I thought the goal was to limit the number of fields of one user..

Comment: If it's just the number of users, this answer is overkill - just use users.find({}, { limit: 5});

Comment: @RuneJeppesen

This can limit the field. First you do {{#each users}} in template. Then under it put {{#each users_1 this}} and then put the template function above in users_1. Reading again I think the poster didn't mean that but when reading it 5 hours ago I immediately got this idea, and tried and it worked.

Edit: If anyone is curious how I did it exactly I'd be happy to share the current code.

Comment: @Bads You are the poster!?
Whether you want to limit the number of posts or the number of fields per post I think you should consider solving it server side in the publications thereby reducing the data sent over the wire. ONLY send the data you need.

Comment: @RuneJeppesen I mean the poster of this answer. And yes I want to limit the information from server, but with my understanding, in this scenario I'd have to send array from server instead of cursor hence loosing reactivity.

Comment: @Bads Okay - but please clarify  if it is posts or fields you want to limit?
And checkout http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection under transform - you will not lose reactivity (I think ;-)

Comment: @RuneJeppesen Thanks for that. Transform does look very promising for this, but man lack of example and proper documentation on meteor docs is killing me sometimes. I guess I will play around with it.

Comment: I can highly recommend the Discover Meteor book!

Comment: @RuneJeppesen : you're right, in the exemple I gave, the 'limit' feature would have done the job. But in the background I figured that Bads problem was also try to manipulate Collection from client side. And that's often what I do, I go for one Collection an rebuild it, since for exemple meteor doesn't support mongo aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Field Specifiers](http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers) to choose what you want.

Comment: I don't want to specify field name. I just want to return first 5 field that it finds in the document.