# Get MongoDB objects between a given range indexes

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, meteorite

How can i fetch the mongodb objects from a starting index to an end index. For example I have 100 objects and i want to get these objects first 1 to 10 then 11 to 20 and then 21 to 30. How can I write a mongodb query which returns me the objects 11 to 20. Thanx

My code is

```
Template.syllabus_design.topics = function () {
    var syllabus = Meteor.syllabi.findOne(Session.get("currentSyllabusId"));
    topics= Meteor.topics.find({subject_id: syllabus.subject_id, level_id: syllabus.level_id})
return topics
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the limit and skip [options](http://docs.meteor.com/#find) in your query.  For items 11-20, you would need:

```
myCollection.find({myquery}, {skip: 10, limit: 10});
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered to a kind of same pb :

[Limit number of field return from mongodb in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086466/limit-number-of-field-return-from-mongodb-in-meteor/21086760#21086760)

Hope it'll help

Comment: I tried this but when i am checking objects[i] it is giving `templates.deps.recompute` error